# Subviews (MPMoviePlayerController) Not Animating With Container View

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm adding an `MPMoviePlayerController` to a container view like so:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.videoURL];
. . .
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.frame;
[self addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

The `self` is the container view. This container view is instantiated off-screen when it is created by a view controller. So the container view resides in a view, and the `MPMoviePlayerController` resides in the container view.

When I animate the container view on screen, it works. Other views slide off and this view slides in. However, the `MPMoviePlayerController` stays put with its frame off-screen. So the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s container view moves on screen, but it does not move with its container view. Is this not allowed, or am I missing something? The code for animating the container view is below:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_LENGTH animations:^() {
    for(int i = beginTag; i < beginTag + [self subviews].count; i++) {
        UIView *viewPointer = [self viewWithTag:i];
        CGRect viewFrame = viewPointer.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.x -= SCREEN_WIDTH_VC;
        viewPointer.frame = viewFrame;
    }
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.vidLoad playVideo];
}];
```

This takes care of animating elements that are on-screen off of the screen, and then bringing off-screen elements onto the screen. I'm glad to hear all suggestions!

Comment: In fact, no subviews of this view are moving with their container view. At this point I am guessing my view hierarchy is not designed/supported well. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - this was a result of my own stupidity. The view hierarchy was indeed working, but when I assigned `self.frame` to `moviePlayer.view.frame`, it took the absolute coordinates of the container view, not relative coordinates.

A silly mistake. Basically, I just had to write

```
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH_VC, SCREEN_HEIGHT_VC);
```

This would place it right on top of the container view, as these coordinates are relative to that container view and not the screen (I just confused myself).